# Authorize ssh from only one subdomain

Tags: linux, ssh, dns

I have a vps and a domain.
I want to be able to connect with ssh to my vps, but only with a subdomain like sub.example.com
Actually, I can connect with my domain, all of my subdomains, and the ip.
Is it possible to do this?

I tried to edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config, adding like `AllowUsers *@ssh.example.com`, avec everytime, after I restart ssh, I cant reconect, and I need to boot my vps with rescue mod to modify the ssh config file, and restart everything to be able to reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to limit ssh access **to** certain (sub)domains  (which you are hosting on a single virtual server). Using `AllowUsers` you limit *user@host* (so where they come **from**). So I guess that is not the way to go.

From the [sshd manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html):

**AllowUsers**
*This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces. If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns. Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized. By default, login is allowed for all users. If the pattern takes the form USER@HOST then USER and HOST are separately checked, restricting logins to particular users from particular hosts*

I don't really know if what you want is possible at all unless you give each (sub)domain a unique ip-address. Then you'll be able to configure sshd to listen to a certain address by specifying `ListenAddress` in `sshd_config`.